# building xamarin.forms 4.8 nuget packages with vs2019 get a build error XliffTasks not found

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

Trying to fix a memory leak in xamarin.forms for uwp.  I got the 4.8 source from the github, followed all the instructions on how to setup the build.  When i build the xamarin.forms.sln i get the following error.

```
"Xamarin.Forms\Xamarin.Forms.sln" (Restore target) (1) ->
(Restore target) ->
 Xamarin.Forms\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.csproj : error N
U1101: Unable to find package XliffTasks. No packages exist with this id in source(s): GrapeCity, Microsoft Visual Stud
io Offline Packages, nuget.org [Xamarin.Forms\Xamarin.Forms.sln]
```

any ideas where i am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: you need to add a [new feedsource in nuget.config](https://github.com/dotnet/xliff-tasks#installing). why do you need the source to fix something? The nugets include the PDBs for profilers like Windows Performance Analyzer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `xliff-tasks`. Add `https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet-eng/nuget/v3/index.json` to your `nuget.config`. For [example](https://github.com/dotnet/xliff-tasks/blob/bece141801e549fda0fda5c0ab96f733b1093515/NuGet.config):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="dotnet-eng" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet-eng/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="dotnet-tools" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet-tools/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="dotnet-public" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet-public/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources />
</configuration>
```